# Why ば and ならない in 解決していかねばならない?

Tags: grammar

> 技術の革新が環境に与える悪影響についても**解決していかねばならない**
>   Simultaneously with the innovation of technology concerning negative influence ...

Can you explain the grammar behind 解決していかねばならない? I know it has a connection with かねる but why -ば and ならない at the end?

Comment: Please try to use more specific titles than "Japanese sentence".

Comment: It does not have a connection with かねる.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ねばねば食べねば, relation between ねば and なければ](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3061/%e3%81%ad%e3%81%b0%e3%81%ad%e3%81%b0%e9%a3%9f%e3%81%b9%e3%81%ad%e3%81%b0-relation-between-%e3%81%ad%e3%81%b0-and-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%91%e3%82%8c%e3%81%b0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「～ねばならない」 means "must", "have to".

---

「解決していかねばならない」 consists of:

解決して -- te-form of 解決する (or, noun 解決 + verb する + particle て)
いか -- 未然形 (imperfective form) of the subsidiary verb いく(行く)
ね -- 仮定形 (hypothetical form) of the negative auxiliary ぬ
ば -- conjunctive particle ば
なら -- 未然形 of なる
ない -- negative auxiliary

So ～ねばならない literally means "doesn't work if... not", but I think you should just learn it as a set phrase, together with its variants: ～なければならない, ～なければいけない, ～なくてはいけない, ～なくてはならない, ～ないといけない, ～ねばならぬ, etc.

Comment: Btw, your translation `技術の革新が環境に与える悪影響についても解決していかねばならない Simultaneously with the innovation of technology concerning negative influence...` >> 技術の革新が環境に与える is a relative clause that modifies 悪影響. "We should also be resolving the negative influences **which** the innovation of technology gives to the environment." or "As for/Concerning negative effects **that** the innovation of technology will have on the environment, we should also be resolving them."

Comment: Thankyou so much, ～ねばならぬ literally means "must" right? I have learned the other form -nakereba naranai and didnt know there is another form such as -nebanaranai. At first I thought it has a connection with かねる Now i understood thanks so much!!!